# How do we add custom fields in Infor syteline

Tags: erp

I have a new requirement to add a custom field called document number in the item form which should be editable.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, In order to get attention/answer you should post/edit the question with your attempts & more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

We should use the following steps to create a custom fields.

1. Creating a user class - The user class definition is the highest level to extend an application database table.
2. Creating user fields - User fields are generic and can be a part of many classes. If the user changes any property of a user field, all user classes inherit the change.
3. Associating the user field with a user class - The UET tools look for this association to place the user fields in the form that belongs to the user class.
4. Linking an application database table with the user class - The association between a table and a class provides the information that UET needs to retrieve, arrange, and display the user fields that belong to a user class. To link the table with the class, define a rule that determines if the record accessed has a valid user class associated with it. If valid data is entered in existing fields to make the rule expression true, the new user field displays.
5. Impacting the schema - Use the UET Impact Schema form to apply the changes you made in the previous steps to all affected databases.